# Can anyone translate these pictures for me?

Tags: arabic-translation

I have these in my apartment, can someone translate them for me. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. The First picture is: "لا اله الا الله محمد رسول الله"
   " La-elaha-elallah and Muhammad Rasulallah"
   which    means there is no God but Allah __ and also: Muhammad is
   the    Messenger of Allah
2. The second picture is: "الله جل جلاله" Allah (jalal-Jalalh)
3. The third picture is: "بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم، ومن يتق الله يجهل له مخرجا ويرزقه من حيث لا يحتسب، صدق الله العظيم" 
   (Almost): In the name of Allah the compassionate the merciful ./. Whoever has Taqwa, Allah will create (show) an escapement (exit) for him and will give him Rizq from the places which he cannot guess them
4. The last picture is again: "محمد رسول الله" Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah
   (Muhammad Rasul allah) (of course there is another picture beside
   that, which is not completely clear)

Comment: I would add the meaning of the third one in some minutes (God willing)

Comment: "another picture" is pic 3; though there is also a little text in left of pic 3; you have forgot sadaqallahu l gazim; i would like also arabic text, it would be copy pastable into dictionaries or translators to verify/check and proof and learn

Answer (score 1):

Even if my dear brother @Ali_________علی has mentioned and answered the Question here are a few points which he apparently missed!

Picture#

1. there's "huwa Allah" = "He's Allah/God" on the top of the picture so the picture says in total: "Huwa Allah/Huwa Allahu, La Ilaha Illa Allah/La Illaha Illa Allahu, Muhammad Rassul Allah/ Muhammadu(n) Rassulu Allahi" = "He'a Allah, There's no God except Allah, Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah"!
2. On top in golden/yellow letters "Allah/Allahu" and in silver/white letters "Jalla-Jallaluh"="exalted/great/dignified in his Majesty"
3. Are in golden/yellow letters a part of Verse (65:2) and on the left hand in silver/white letters Verse (65:3) which build together two verses from surat at-Talaq ([65:2-3](http://legacy.quran.com/65/2-3)) more exactly the bold parts:

> " **And whoever fears Allah - He will make for him a way out** (2) **And
>   will provide for him from where he does not expect. And whoever relies
>   upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him. Indeed, Allah will
>   accomplish His purpose.** Allah has already set for everything a
>   [decreed] extent.(3)"
>
> **waman yattaqi Allaha yaj'al lahu makhraja(n) (2) Wa yarzuqhu min
>   haythu la yahtasib** waman yatawakkal 'Aala Allahi fahuwa hasbuh inna
>   Allaha balighu amrihi qad ja'ala Allahu likulli shay-in qadra (3)

and in silver/white letters you find on top "Bismi Allahi ar-Rahmani ar-Rahim" = "In the name of Allah the compassionate the merciful" and at the bottom "Sadaqa Allahu al-'adhim"="truthful/true is what Allah the almighty said"

4. It shows in golden/yellow Letter the name of the Messenger "Mohammad" (peace be upon him) and in silver/white letters "Rassul Allah/ Rassulu Llah"="Messenger of Allah"

Answer (score 0):

- Image 1:

  > لا إله إلا الله محمد الرسول الله
  >
  > > There is no God but **ALLAH** and **MUHAMMAD** pbuh is the messenger of **ALLAH**.
- Image 2

  > الله جل جلاله
  >
  > > **ALLAH** dignified HIS majesty.
- Image 3

  > `بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم`،
  >   **وَيَرْزُقْهُ مِنْ حَيْثُ لَا يَحْتَسِبُ وَمَنْ يَتَوَكَّلْ عَلَى اللَّهِ فَهُوَ حَسْبُهُ**
  >   `صدق الله العظيم`
  >
  > > `In the name of ALLAH the most gracious the most merciful.`
  > >     **And will provide for him from where he does not expect. And whoever relies upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him.**
  > >     `True is what ALLAH has said.` [[65:3]](https://quran.com/65/3)
- Image 4

  > محمد رسول الله
  >
  > > **MUHAMMAD** `peace be upon him` is the messenger of **ALLAH**.

Comment: Image one illa الا  (except) is not ila إلى (to, towards) only the first is corerct. Image 3 you have posted the wrong part of the verse 65:3 and missed the whole verse 65:2. Image 4 there's no alif and laam in rasssul لرسول as you posted in Arabic!